# Arima - Tests detect nonseasonality of time series

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, kpss-test

I have a following time series:

```
 36035 30074 39956 33935 39356 35065 42497 37562 42133 46456 37641 39701 46817
 38346 41736 41220 56562 50693 44526 45808 48889 42228 34534 37228 38919 32653
 33361 34933 37872 40907 43287 43901 41313 45780 33867 28645 27501 29818 36292
 29057 34617 35370 36673 49912 43972 37943 30822 35246 35884 42919 42668 38090
 35894 41277 52415 49476 42329 48945 47481 39562 36412 37702 44190 37988 38908
 38446 43030 44127 39225 44643 52004 41293 40192 43305 45681 52912 53325 49381
 57756 67006 53510 56910 40407 53428
```

kpss, ocsb tests detect stationarity - no need for first and seasonal differencing. However, the best model (MAPE, MASE, ... on test  sample)  is sarima (3,1,1)(1,1,1). Please explain why this happens. 
Analysis is limited only on (s-)arima models.

Comment: Please describe how you found this "best" model.  What is the "this" that you want to have explained?

Comment: When I look at the time series,  acf and pacf (only 1st annual lag is significant), after I perform above mentioned tests I conclude that there is no need for first and seasonal differencing. But the series has a slightly increasing trend (kpss before and after first differencing proves this) so then I apply first differencing. Based on AICc I select the best model, however, its MAPE, MASE... measures on test sample are much lower than when I use SARIMA (3,1,1)(1,1,1). "THIS" is a gap between tests which say no differencing and quality of results which point on differencing. Regards.

Comment: "Based on AICc I select the best model": okay, but best model *from among which candidates*? You cannot possibly have examined all models.  It sounds like you have interpreted some graphics one way and some of your automatic selection procedures are suggesting a different interpretation, but there shouldn't be any surprise about that.  What is unclear is whether we need to address the psychological question of how you are interpreting the graphics or the statistical question of why different statistical tests can suggest (slightly) different conclusions.

Comment: Followed two paths - first via tests, the second based on experience with similar time series. First says ARIMA, but tests give bad results, the second says SARIMA but I do can not verify this option because tests give different result. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @whuber aptly pointed out , it all depends upon the quality of the expert opinion that you are relying on and the scope of their search as it relates to "the best model ". The issue here is simply how many models did the expert software/person consider i.e. what is the pool of candidates or "from among which candidates was the model selected" . I took you 84 values into an expert system that I have helped to develop which considers a broad set including possible fixed structure such as level shifts and seasonal pulses while entertaining an expanded list of possible ARIMA structures. This is the model that AUTOBOX developed [image] suggests a simple level shift and 1 pulse (anomaly) and a seasonal (august) effect starting at year 2 with an ar(1) coefficient (1,0,0)(0,0,0) 12 . Your software apparently/probably over differenced reflecting inability to include a determinstic level shift and then compensated by including a cancelling seasonal ma terms culminating . I hope this answers your question " as to why this happens" .

[image]

UPON FINDING THAT MODEL SELECTION HAD BEEN DONE ON 72 VALUES ... WE HAVE

[image]   AND   [image]   with similar conclusions about seasonality,arima structure and anomalies (two in this case ) The forecasts for the next 12 periods are presented here [image] and here [image]

ADDED AN ANSWER TO THE LATEST QUERY FROM OP.

The residuals from the last model present no suggestion of trend or structure of any kind. The proof is in the pudding/residualls so to speak. The tests you are using are flawed when there are gaussian violations like pulses (2) and a seasonal pulse. They incorrectly suggest seasonal ar 12 when all that is needed is a seasonal pulse.

[image]

Comment: IrishStat thanks on your response. I forgot to mention that I use 72 observations for training and 12 for testing. However, auto.arima suggests ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,0,1)[12] with drift for 84 obesrvations. For 72 observations ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0)[12] with non-zero mean. However, this model shows much lower performances on test case than sarima model SARIMA (3,1,1)(1,1,1) which I selected based on trial and error.

Comment: a lot of trial and apparently a lot of error (grin) ....

Comment: Sorry, still in doubt, why the system suggests a solution without first differencing, and tests (kpss and adf) say that there is a trend and non stationarity?

Comment: Additional, SARIMA(3,1,1)(1,1,1) gives MAPE on train sample 7.8%, on test sample 15.6%, and automatically generated solution ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0) 9.9 and 20% respectively. May you provide some explanation for this please?

Comment: The residuals (see plot in my answer ) from the last model present no suggestion of trend or structure of any kind. The proof is in the pudding/residuals so to speak. The tests you are using are flawed when there are gaussian violations like pulses (2) and a seasonal pulse. They incorrectly suggest seasonal ar 12 when all that is needed is a seasonal pulse.